# React Calculator: How to prevent multiple decimals?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calculator

I have almost finished building a simple calculator, using React. 
I just have a trouble with multiple decimals. What I try to do is writing a condition but it doesn't work. Could you help me, please?

Here is a part of my code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            input: '0'
        };
    }


    addToInput = e => {
        const value = e.target.value;
        const oldValue = this.state.input;

        if (this.state.input != '0') {
            this.setState({ input: (this.state.input + value) });

        } else if (value == '.' && oldValue.includes('.')) {
            console.log('Mulitple decimals');
        } else {
            this.setState({ input: value });
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (<Button addToInput={ this.addToInput } />);
    }
}

class Button extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (

            <div className="row">
                <button
                    value="."
                    id="decimal"
                    onClick={ this.props.addToInput }
                >.
                </button>
                <button
                    value="0"
                    id="zero"
                    onClick={ this.props.addToInput }
                >0
                </button>
                <button
                    value="-"
                    id="subtract"
                    onClick={ this.props.addToInput }
                >-
                </button>
            </div>


        );
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your code is missing a closing bracket for `addToInput`.

Comment: You are right. Thank you!
Though my original code has the brackets. It is not a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you `addToInput` like this:

```
    addToInput = e => {
        const value = e.target.value;
        const oldValue = this.state.input;

        if (value === '.' && oldValue.includes('.')) {
            console.log('Mulitple decimals');
            return;
        }

        if (this.state.input !== '0') {
            this.setState({ input: (this.state.input + value) });

        } else {
            this.setState({ input: value });
        }
    };
```

Why you have had a problem:

```
    addToInput = e => {
        const value = e.target.value;
        const oldValue = this.state.input;

        if (this.state.input !== '0') {
            // after first addToInput you will end up here ALWAYS
            this.setState({ input: (this.state.input + value) });
        } else if (value === '.' && oldValue.includes('.')) {
            // You will never be here because this.state.input !== '0' is always true after first addToInput
            console.log('Mulitple decimals'); 
        } else {
            // you will end up here only when you lunch your addToInput first time
            this.setState({ input: value });
        }
    };
```

Comment: This worked! Now I understood, thank you very much!

Comment: @KseniaKartoshkina usually it is a good tone to accept answer that solved your problem :)

Comment: oops, sorry! I didn't know how to do. It was my first question here. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the value coming in, check if it's a `.` and check if the input already has one. If it does, do nothing, otherwise add the value to the end of the input:

```
addToInput = e => {
  const { value } = e.target;
  const { input } = this.state;

  if (value === "." && input.includes(".")) {
    return;
  }

  this.setState({ input: `${input}${value}` });
};
```

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't use condition input.includes("."). I don't know why. I edited my code, so it logs the phrase "Multiple decimals", if input.includes("."), but it doesnt log anything.

Comment: @KseniaKartoshkina where are you rendering the input? What is the value of `this.state.input` every time you call `addToInput()`?

Answer (score 0):

Well regular expression will help you.

```
const regex = /^[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$/;
```

Then you can check your value:

```
regex.test('222') // true
regex.test('222.') // false
regex.test('222.0') // true
regex.test('222.0.1') // false
regex.test('222.01234') // true
regex.test('abc') // false
```

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with my code but your solution doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

`(value == '.' && oldValue.includes('.')`
Are you sure here must be `&&` ? When your new value EXACTLY `.` and old one contains `.` you will get `false` - `(false && true) === false`. 

Then, try following

Add `regex = /^[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$/;` to constructor.

And `else if (value == '.' && oldValue.includes('.'))` must be replaced with
`else if (this.regex.test(value) || oldValue.includes('.'))`

Hope this helps.